# Sort Array function in C

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I've written this function to sort an integer array, here flag is an indicator whether to sort the array in ascending or descending and size is the size of the array. Can you tell me where I've written something wrong, I've checked the algorithm too.

```
void sortArray(int a[], int flag, int size) {
    int temp, index;
    int start = 0;
    int smallest = start;
    if (flag) {
        while (start < size) {
            index = start;
            while (index < size) {
                if(a[index] < a[smallest]) {
                    smallest = index;
                }
                index++;
            }
            temp = a[smallest];
            a[smallest] = a[start];
            a[start] = temp;
            start++;
        }
    }
    else{
        while (start < size) {
            index = start;
            while (index < size) {
                if(a[index] > a[smallest]) {
                   smallest = index;
                }
                index++;
            }
            temp = a[smallest];
            a[smallest] = a[start];
            a[start] = temp;
            start++;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: have you tried to run it and checked the output?

Comment: If you're getting some error, then post error too.

Comment: `smallest` set each outer loop. E.g `index = start;` --> `smallest = start; index = start + 1;`

Comment: Yes, i've checked, it is not sorting it properly.

Comment: I am not getting an error, it is not sorting the array properly

Comment: before entering the inner while set `smallest` to `start`

Comment: Ok I am going to try that GAURANG VYAS

Comment: It worked!, thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `smallest = index;` before your second while loop, like this

```
    if (flag) {
    while (start < size) {
        index = start;
        smallest = index;
        while (index < size) {
            if(a[index] < a[smallest]) {
                smallest = index;
            }
            index++;
        }
        temp = a[smallest];
        a[smallest] = a[start];
        a[start] = temp;
        start++;
    }
}
```

without this addition, your loop keeps checking for elements that are already sorted, and that messes up the algorithm